# Why does my ArrayList is taking input like this?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

So, I have couple of strings coming from f:checkbox from JSP. 
Now the pattern of value is Which is JSON:

```
{"firstName":"TIMOTHY","lastname":"WALKER","price":"50"}
```

If I select two check box, the content of list be like :

```
0 :{"firstName":"TIMOTHY","lastname":"WALKER","price":"50"}
1 :{"firstName":"ANNE","lastname":"WALKER","price":"150"}
```

But if I select only one checkbox, the content if list be like :

```
    0 :{"firstName":"TIMOTHY"
1 :"lastName":"WALKER"
2 :"price":100}
```

Here is my Javascript code which is assigning values to checkbox -

```
var Service={}
 <c:forEach items="${MERCHPAXORDINALS}" var="paxOrdinal"  varStatus="paxStatus">
   var ServiceArray={};
   ServiceArray['firstName']="${MERCHPAXORDINALS[paxOrdinal.key]['FirstName']}";
   ServiceArray['lastname']="${MERCHPAXORDINALS[paxOrdinal.key]['LastName']}";
   ServiceArray['price']="${MERCHPAXORDINALS[paxOrdinal.key]['Rate']}";
   ServiceArray['Ordinal']="${MERCHPAXORDINALS[paxOrdinal.key]['Ordinal']}"
    Service['${paxOrdinal.key}']=ServiceArray;
 </c:forEach>
  function changeCost(index){
if(document.getElementById(index).checked)
    document.getElementById(index).value=JSON.stringify(Service[index]);
  display(TotalFees);
}
```

Additionally, I have to Parse these strings into JSON,
I am using org.json to parse them. And when I select only one Checkbox,
I get this error (which is obvious) -

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 23 [character 24 line 1]
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "java"?

Comment: Because the problem arises in ArrayList only of my bean class.

Comment: @Fildor - I guess because there's java (JSP) code in there.

Comment: @vidit Ah, right. Before first coffee here ;)